# Editing an item in a table using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, forms

I'm new to programming currently practicing with angularjs.  I'm trying to edit an item in a table from an array, but I don't seem to be following the logic correctly. When I click the submit button after I edit the product, I'm logging the index to the console but it's giving me a -1.  Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong with my edit logic, I'm trying to console log the index to ensure I'm editing the exiting product.

I've added my code to fiddle

jsfiddle.net/andresq820/z9gm3gwv/#&togetherjs=rJyE9E96nk

Comment: should add this to `jsfiddle` or `codepen` for others to check

Comment: I moved the code in jsFiddle to codepen and was not able to bring the edit feature as i think it is in your local script file. Can you check http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XpGjje